How to combine the TEXTJOIN formula with COUNTIF in Google Spreadsheet
I have some data like this




A




1
DATA


2
Aplle


3
Aplle


4
Avocado


5
Banana


6
Banana


7
Coconut


8
Breadfruit


9
Banana


10
Coconut


11
Banana


12
Avocado


13
Coconut


14
Breadfruit


15
Breadfruit


16
Banana


17
Durian


18
Breadfruit


19
Breadfruit


20
Banana


21
Coconut



If I use =TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,UNIQUE(A2:A21)) then the result will be like Apple, Avocado, Banana, Coconut, Breadfruit, Durian. I want to combine the unique data and calculate the count of the data. the results are as follows Apple 2, Avocado 2, Banana 6, Coconut 4, Breadfruit 5, Durian 1

You should clarify the output. Make it a table.

Try this:
=TEXTJOIN(", ",false,BYROW(LET(x,UNIQUE(B1:B),y,BYROW(x,LAMBDA(z, COUNTIF(B1:B,z))),ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(HSTACK(x,y),ROWS(x)-1,2)), LAMBDA(r, JOIN(" ", r))))

References:
Unique
ByRow

Another alternative using QUERY function;
=QUERY(A2:A, "Select A, Count(A) Where A Is Not Null Group By A Label A 'DATA'")

.



You may try:
=reduce(,unique(tocol(A2:A,1)),lambda(a,c,textjoin(", ",1,{a,c&" "&countif(A:A,c)})))



Just another option-
=textjoin(", ",1,let(x,unique(tocol(A2:A,1)),index(x & " " & countifs(A2:A,x))))



Here's one formula you could try:
=LET(list, UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, NOT(ISBLANK(A2:A)))), count, ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(A2:A, list)), res, ARRAYFORMULA(list & " " & count), TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, res))

Output: Apple 2, Avocado 2, Banana 6, Coconut 4, Breadfruit 5, Durian 1.
References

LET
ARRAYFORMULA
FILTER

